# UDP code need to rewrite

Tags: java

Wanted to implement this code into one of the class, not main class, it will need try and catch for IOException, how do I place it?

when call `sendUPD(valueData);` it will send string to the function.

```
private boolean Notconnected = true;

private void sendUDP(String s){
 if(Notconnected){
   DatagramSocket datgramSocket = new DatagramSocket(4455); //<--- try catch
   Notconnected = false;
  }
  try {

   byte[] buf = new byte[512];

        DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        datgramSocket.receive(incomingPacket);

        //What did we just receive?
        //String s = new String(incomingPacket.getData(),0,incomingPacket.getLength());

        if(!(s.equals("quit"))){
         String responseString = s;
   buf = responseString.getBytes("UTF-8");

         InetAddress address = incomingPacket.getAddress();
         int port = incomingPacket.getPort();

         DatagramPacket outgoingPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);

         datgramSocket.send(outgoingPacket);
   } 
  } catch (IOException e) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the IOException caught in your existing try block.  Would you do anything differently when opening the socket?

I notice that if you can't open the socket you still try and receive and send data with it.  How does that work?

It looks like you're just trying to get it to compile.  In that case, you can move that `if(Notconnected)`block in the existing try.  That has the added advantage of not trying to receive/send if the socket cannot be opened, as the Exception will jump you down to the catch block at the bottom.

There's still quite a bit more work to do to get the implementation just right.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is poorly structured. Instead of creating it on demand, you should create the DatagramSocket in the constructor for that class, and let that constructor throw an IOException if it fails. Then you can never have this problem.